# Spark MLlib Library does not provide libraries for Content-based Recommendation Systems?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I'm trying to make use of spark mllib to implement a Content-based recommendation system.

I have just realized that they only offer an implementation of Alternating Least Squares (ALS).

Is my understanding correct?

Does any other framework provide libraries to implement content based recommendation?

References:

- https://databricks-training.s3.amazonaws.com/movie-recommendation-with-mllib.html
- http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-guide.html

Answer (score 3):

Spark ML/MLLib doesn't provide any *Content-based Collaborative Filtering* (CBF) implementation out-of-the-box because of the nature of the technique. CBF needs needs some heavy feature engineering and profile building.

Thus a generic method such used in `ALS` which is *Matrix Factorization* is quite impossible to generalize for the time being in this context.

Nevertheless, `spark` provides the essential part in building such recommenders.

Answer (score 0):

For an alternative, you could look at [the universal recommender](https://github.com/actionml/universal-recommender). It provides a basis for building recommenders based on multiple features.